# Sympy plot function in variable space under certain conditions for variables

Tags: python, sympy

I am still exploring sympy and wanted to use it to plot following function in 3d space.

```
import sympy as sym

a, h, x, b, k, y, c, l = sym.symbols("a h x b k y c l")

eq = a*h*x+b*k*y+c*l*(1-(x+y))
```

is it possible to do this in conjunction with following conditions (probably not in correct code, but I hope you guess what I mean):

```
(0<=x<=1), (0<=y<=1), ((x+y)<=1)
```

for plotting, I substitute all symbols with knowns, except for x and y, and I would like to have these two within their ranges, specified by above conditions...
how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to handle the third condition (`x+y<=1`) but otherwise this should be a start:

```
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a, h, x, b, k, y, c, l = sym.symbols("a h x b k y c l")

eq = a*h*x+b*k*y+c*l*(1-(x+y))

values = {a:1,h:2,b:3,k:4,c:5,l:6}
eqv = eq.subs(values)
f = lambdify((x, y), eqv)

xv = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
yv = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xv, yv)

Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attempt, but it is not a good answer, as the third condition is of course important. Is there a way in sympy to specifically only allow numbers for x and y wich meet these conditions. E.g. substitute with these inequalities somehow solved for x and y or so?

Comment: There are various ways to do different things here in SymPy. Your question is really about plotting though. It isn't entirely clear to me what you actually want as an output. I've given an answer that should get you something close. You've said it's "not a good answer" though so good luck finding something better.